# TCPDf error in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, open-source, tcpdf

I am using TCPDF, but i encountered these problem.
please give me solution.

---

**A PHP Error was encountered**

Severity: Notice

Message: Use of undefined constant K_CELL_HEIGHT_RATIO - assumed 'K_CELL_HEIGHT_RATIO'

Filename: libraries/Loader.php

Line Number: 928

---

**A PHP Error was encountered**

Severity: Warning

Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at D:\xampp\htdocs\small projects\project1\system\libraries\Exceptions.php:166)

Filename: tcpdf/tcpdf.php

Line Number: 8060

---

**TCPDF ERROR**: Some data has already been output to browser, can't send PDF file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [this](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/TCPDF-CodeIgniter_Integration/). You probably doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Check this [CodeIgniter Forum](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewreply/846525/)

just comment line 3 to 8 on libraries/pdf.php

> your code should look like this:
>
> /* 
>     override the default TCPDF config file
>   if(!defined(‘K_TCPDF_EXTERNAL_CONFIG’))
>   {
>   define(‘K_TCPDF_EXTERNAL_CONFIG’,
>   TRUE); }
>   */